# nginx proxy - aws emr cluster [multiple UIs]

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

**Description:** When launching an EMR cluster each application is configured to expose its UI.

**Goal:** Access the UIs through Nginx using friendly URLs without port number

**Details:**

> 1. Each UI is on a different port
> 2. Basic Authentication (htpass)
> 3. Some UIs redirect you to the private-dns-record of the EMR master (can fix them manually, need Nginx to do it)
> 4. UI Ports: 8088,8890,8888,18080,50070

**What has been done?**

A) Following [this article](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/security/authentication.html) we are able to access Zeppelin

B) We tried to modify that configuration to allow more locations
    The logic behind that was that by doing that we could access the nginx with '/somename' and be redirect using 'upstream' to the relevant port on the EMR master but sadly it does not work.

```
location /hadoop {
  proxy_pass hxxp://hadoop
}
```

C) We tried rewriting rules but once we put

`rewrite ^/hadoop(.*)$ /$1 permenant;`

Under `/somename` it actually goes to:

`location /`

***Question:*** How can we use simple friendly URLs such as hxxp://mynginx/hadoop to access the UIs?

> Example: `http://nginx/app` should redirect to `http://upstream-server:8088`

Comment: Please include the configuration in the question as text, not as a link.

Comment: This question does not refer to any specific configuration but rather to "How can I achieve functionality".
To simplify things:
I would like to use a single point of entry [Nginx] using the following format:
`http://nginx/ui1`
and transfer the request to a backend system where that UI lives on a specific port without breaking the UI.

I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way.

Comment: I think the best way to understand it is: `http://nginx/app` should redirect to `http://upstream-server:8088`

Comment: You need to add `proxy_pass` to the backend service, and then fix the URLs it writes on the backend service setup. nginx cannot do URL replacements in the HTML code returned by the backend.

Comment: Hmm, then it seems I can't do what I want.
Too bad, I thought it might be 'not the right way'.

Thank you!

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - question though, The Zeppelin configuration (from the link) does work in that way.
Could you explain to me why that works and I can't add hadoop to work in that way too?
Does it relate to how 'location /' works?

(post as an answer so I can award you the points)

Comment: Actually I misunderstood the question, my comment is not relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood correctly, you have a `location` block like this:

```
location /hadoop {
    rewrite ^/hadoop(.*) /$1 permanent;
    proxy_pass http://hadoop;
}
```

The `rewrite` statement above sends a 301 Moved Permanently response back to the browser, with the rules you have written. Therefore the user is redirected to the `/` URI when you access `/hadoop`.

Most likely you want this:

```
location ~ ^/hadoop(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://hadoop$1;
}
```

Here we capture the part after `/hadoop` into a variable, and then use that variable with the `proxy_pass` destination.

However, you still need to fix the URLs the Hadoop backend is sending back to the client in its HTML code, otherwise it is not returning URLs with `/hadoop` prefix.